# Is it allowed for a man to live with Non Mehram Relatives?

Tags: halal-haram, non-mahram

Assalam o Alaikum, My name is Zain.

In a Few days, I will be moving to Dubai to set a Career. As I am on a Budget. I had booked Bed Spaces in Dubai.

My Father's Niece (My 1st Cousin) also lives in Dubai. She lives in her own house. When she got to know that I am moving to Dubai. She offered me to live in her house. At first I rejected. But she didn't agreed and forced me and my Parents.

Now my Parents are also convincing me that you should live in her house. At this moment I am very confused.

**I want to know that is it allowed in Islam?Can I Live in my Cousins house?**

She is 19 years older than me. She is Divorced and has 3 Kids who live with her. She has offered me my own room to live in. At this moment. She is a Software Engineer and is at work in the Day time and Her kids are studying so they will be in school in the day time.

Can anyone please assist me out. It seems ok to me Because I will sleep alone in my own room.

Comment: You cannot stay at the house of a non mahram. Your only option is that a male mahram is there while you are there, but you didn't even add any information on her children's age or gender, so your question can hardly be answered more appropriately.

Comment: I don't know the exact age of her children but she has 2 daughters and 1 son and all are under 12 years old. The problem isn't about her children because I am not going to permanently live there. Just gonna live there till I am used to the place and stable.

Answer (score 1):

But most likely 90% you'll see her ; part of arms etc...
She might be cooking etc... and she might not wear hijab properly ;

Let alone the difference of opinion between hijab & niqab; i'm for niqab, inside me something tells me it's not good to look at hijabis.

I suppose that the fact that she offered you to live in her house...
means that she doesn't know about cousin being non-mahram ;
& exact rulings & free mixing

I'll probably gather more info ; after i'll tell you InshaAllah

Just tell them that you can't since she's not mahram to you ; After you're gonna feel guilty  by going in that house , struggling  to not see;

Me too i was in situation like this* ,they were somehow related to me but not my mahram, it was a video call; but i  didn't look & my family told that i didn't look at them

*almost hijabi ; i didn't say how i managed, the answer would lenghten

[THe niqab is  compulsory ,see this; islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/11774/ruling-on-covering-the-face-with-detailed-evidence)

Will you feel comfortable in someone's house; using bathrooms etc....
You don't loose much if you reject the offer; you can say to her that she is not a mahram.

So basically since you'll see her ; that becomes haram; in a theoritical case where he won't be alone with her ; and' no seeing' that would be halal ;[Is it permissible for her sister’s husband to stay overnight with them in their house?](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/52814/is-it-permissible-for-her-sisters-husband-to-stay-overnight-with-them-in-their-house)

But if you stay like for 1 day & are sure of avoiding fitna ; then you can

ALso she may come back home earlier  ; than schools ; i don't know

Comment: This does hardly even answer the question.

Comment: Since he'll probably see her; & he should avoid it

Comment: Well you already allowed him to stay in, without any back up.

Comment: But i  basically said since he'll se her ; that becomes haram; in a theoritical case where he won't be alone with her ; and no seeing that would be halal